# Retrieving Reviews from Amazon using JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to retrive reviews from a particular webpage in Amazon and what I have now is this:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.com/Presto-06006-Kitchen-Electric-Multi-Cooker/product-reviews/B002JM202I/ref=sr_1_2_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1").get();
    String title = doc.title();

    Element reviews = doc.getElementById("productReviews");
    System.out.println(reviews);
```

This gives me the block of html which has the reviews but I want only the text without all the tags div etc. I want to then write all this information into a file. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Jsoup has plenty of facilities for extracting information, and surely you've gone through the tutorials (they're not that big). So on that note, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Use `text()` method

```
System.out.println(reviews.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

While `text()` will get you a bunch of text, you'll want to first use jsoup's `select(...)` methods to subdivide the problem into individual review elements. I'll give you the first big division, but it will be up to you to subdivide it further:

```
public static List<Element> getReviewList(Element reviews) {
  List<Element> revList = new ArrayList<Element>();
  Elements eles = reviews.select("div[style=margin-left:0.5em;]");
  for (Element element : eles) {
     revList.add(element);
  }
  return revList;
}
```

If you analyze each element, you should see how amazon further subdivides the information held including the title of the review, the date of the review and the body of the text it holds.